# perl threads: is_joinable vs is_running

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
while ($thr->is_running() {
    # do something
}
```

vs

```
while (! $thr->joinable()) {
    # do something
}
```

Is there any difference between the two?
When would a programmer use one over the other and vice versa?

I am assuming you cant join a thread if it's running so arent they basically the same thing?

If so, why does perl provides two different ways to check the status of a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation :

```
$thr->is_running()
Returns true if a thread is still running 
(i.e., if its entry point function has not yet finished or exited).

$thr->is_joinable()
Returns true if the thread has finished running, 
is not detached and has not yet been joined. In other words, 
the thread is ready to be joined, and a call to $thr->join() will not block.
```

So the difference stems from the way detached threads are treated.
i.e $thread->is_running() would return true if the thread is running irrespective of whether it is detached or not

but  "not $thread->is_joinable()" would return true even if a  thread is detached but has stopped running.

Example:

1) detached thread

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub do_nothing {
  print("in thread\n");
  sleep(30);
  return;
}


my $t = threads->create(\&do_nothing);
$t->detach();

while  ($t->is_running()) {
 print("is running\n");
 sleep(4);
}
if ($t->is_joinable()) {
  print("is joinable\n");
}
else {
  print("not joinable\n");
}
exit;
```

Exampled : a non-detached thread

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub do_nothing {
  print("in thread\n");
  sleep(30);
  return;
}

my $t = threads->create(\&do_nothing);

while  ($t->is_running()) {
 print("is running\n");
 sleep(4);
}
if ($t->is_joinable()) {
  print("is joinable\n");
}
else {
  print("not joinable\n");
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 7):

`is_joinable` is not the same as `!is_running`.

- `is_joinable` checks for

  ```
   (thread->state & PERL_ITHR_FINISHED) &&
  !(thread->state & PERL_ITHR_DETACHED) &&
  !(thread->state & PERL_ITHR_JOINED)
  ```
- `is_running` checks for

  ```
  !(thread->state & PERL_ITHR_FINISHED)
  ```

So

- A detached thread that finished is neither running nor joinable.
- A thread that's already been joined is neither running nor joinable.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

A thread is "joinable" if it has not been joined or detached, and is no longer running.   That is to say, it provides a poll interface to the condition that joining the thread would block on.

Finished running, not yet joined, not detached == joinable

Not yet finished running, not yet joined, not detached == running.

See [Perl Threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html).

Comment: but if its not joinable then it means it's running. so by checking for !is_joinable(), you are doing the same check as is_running(), no?

Comment: As I said above, "Not yet finished running, not yet joined, not detached".  So, a thread that was already joined is neither running nor joinable, for example.